# Shouldn't accessing @Whatever::whatever produce at least a warning instead of an empty array?

Tags: perl, variables

In the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = %Whatever::whatever;
my @array = @Whatever::whatever;
print Dumper \@array;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

My understanding is that @Whatever::whatever is accessing the symbol table, and doesn't produce an error message because symbol table is a hash. But why there isn't at least a warning message for accessing a non-existing element?

Comment: Interesting: `my @array = @Whatever;` does generate an error, of course.

Comment: I would say instead that `@Whatever::whatever` identifies a dynamically scoped array named `@whatever` in the `Whatever` package, rather than that is it *"accessing the symbol table ... [somewhat as] a hash."*  Qualified identifiers like that have always avoided `strict`ures.

Comment: @pilcrow thanks. could you please put this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(adapting/migrating from a comment)*

I would say instead that `@Whatever::whatever` identifies a dynamically scoped array named `@whatever` in the `Whatever` package, rather than that is it "accessing the symbol table ... [somewhat as] a hash."

Qualified identifiers like that have always avoided strictures (see the docs for [`strict 'vars'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html#strict-vars)).

Answer (score 12):

Because it's almost impossible to catch a global variable in a state of non-existence in Perl. As soon as you mention one by name — even just to take a reference to it — it exists. And because arrays and hashes are different from scalars; a scalar comes into existence holding the value `undef`, which triggers a "use of uninitialized value" warning when used for most purposes; but arrays and hashes come into existence as *empty* arrays and hashes, and an empty array or hash isn't exceptional enough to warn about!

Comment: It's only impossible if you construe the problem too narrowly because strict does a good job of solving that problem. The catch is that an exception was specifically carved out of strict for fully-qualified names. One just needs to be a bit more careful using those.